# Yii2 Path format recursive URL

Tags: url, recursion, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am not good at English so i will try to be as clear as possible:

I have a project in Yii2 that has an advanced template, in the database i have a recursive table that represents a tree of categories and entries, you can imagine it as a folder tree that can have unlimited docs and folders (a folder inside another folder is possible), i have created the url in this format;

localhost://my-project/root-category/sub-cat-A/sub-cat-B/25-document

i need tho get the last section of the current Url because, the entire Url can have N levels before the entry that is located in the last section of the Url in the format below:

```
<id:\d+>-<slug:[A-Za-z0-9-_.]+>
```

But i  don't know about any Url rule that could resolve this.

Appreciate your answers.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by myself and i am going to tell you how to solve or if any of you can improve this answer:

i am using the codemix/yii2-localeurls extension, i means that i had to extend the codemix\localeurls\UrlManager class and overwrite the parseRequest method like this:

```
public function parseRequest( $request ) {
    $pathInfo    = $request->getPathInfo();
    $matches     = 0;
    $has_matches = preg_match( '%(bussiness-lines|lineas-de-negocio)\/(.)+\/%', $pathInfo, $matches );

    if ( $has_matches ) {
        /*
         * GET THE LAST SECTION FROM THE URL
         */
        $explode_patInfo = explode( '/', $pathInfo );
        $tree_element    = end( $explode_patInfo );

        /*
         * SEPARATES THE ID AND THE SLUG FROM THE URL
         */
        $tree_element_explode = explode( '-', $tree_element );
        $tree_element_id      = reset( $tree_element_explode );

        unset( $tree_element_explode[0] );

        $tree_element_slug = implode( '-', $tree_element_explode );

        /*
         * RETURN THE CONTROLLER/ACTION AND ITS PARAMS TO PROCESS THE REQUEST
         */
        if ( $tree_element !== false ) {
            return [
                'site/get-tree-element',
                [
                    'id'   => $tree_element_id,
                    'slug' => $tree_element_slug
                ]
            ];
        }
    }

    //IF THE REQUEST DOES NOT CORRESPOND TO MY CUSTOM URL RULE, LETS THE PARENT DO THE JOB
    return parent::parseRequest( $request );
}
```

I am sharing this hoping that can help any of you guys.

Peace.